# Method to tackle match counting in django

Tags: python, django, models, django-queryset

ive been trying to hack away and figure out how to solve this on my own for a few hours but i can't seem to think of an elegant solution for this. I was wondering if anyone can help.

Heres the model layout (example)

```
Model A:
candyBarChoices

Model B:
snackLog
```

Ok so basically the dilemma is this. In the database there are about 15 candy bar choices. Every day when the user logs what they ate, they choose a candy bar. My question is, what is an efficient way to "tally" up each of the candy bar choices given a set of snack logs?

For example: if i provided a QuerySet of 15 snack logs, sometimes the user could have ate multiple candy bars on that day and therefore each snack log could have multiple candy bars. How can i run through this query set and create a compiled data set of the total number of a certain candy bar they ate?

I've come up with multiple really messy solutions using dictionaries, etc. But none of them work without screwing up .. help please.

Comment: Please show some proper models. What sort of field is `candyBarChoices`, for example? How does it relate to User?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post actual models to help clarify your setup. It looks like you're trying to aggregate over a model instance's related objects. If so, look at the docs on [QuerySet aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset).